# Finding a degree-2 polynomial that sits under the Harmonic Numbers.

Tags: asymptotics

Does there exist a degree-2 polynomial with positive acceleration such that the real extension of the harmonic numbers surpasses it for all future values?

This was too big of a title and it's a really big mouthful, so I'll further elaborate on what I'm looking for.

$$
p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \quad \quad a > 0, \quad (b, c) \in \mathbb R^2
$$

Above is the family of polynomials I care about. Positive acceleration (the highest degree term's coefficient), other coefficients just need to be real.

$$
H_k = \sum_{n = 1}^x \frac 1 n
$$

Above is the definition of the $k$th Harmonic Number.

$$
H_x = H_k \quad \quad x \in \mathbb N
$$

$H_x$ will be the real extension of $H_k$ to the reals.

$$
H_x = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - y^x}{1 - y} dy
$$

My question is now, does there exist $p(x)$ as defined above, such that $p(x_0 + c) < H_{x_0 + c}$ for some $x_0$ and $c > 0$?

Comment: Another way to look at it. The "derivative" of harmonics, $H_{k+1}-H_k$, is $1/(k+1)$ which is always $<1$. But a polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has "derivative" $p(x+1)-p(x)=2ax+b+a$. This grows without a bound, and is $>2$ for large enough $x$, say when $x>x_0$. Therefore whatever "early" lead the harmonics might have gotten (possibly with a suitable choice of $b$ and $c$) will quickly begin to diminish  for $x>x_0$. At least by one, when you increase $x$ by one, so sooner rather than later the harmonics will lose.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that was a bad copy of a formula. I'll correct it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If you post your explanation as an answer, I'll accept it. It's sufficient.